# Difference between date and current date, if statement?

Tags: sql

I have a table with four columns:

- id;
- datefrom;
- dateto;
- user id.

I need to calculate the difference between datefrom and dateto (datefrom-dateto) in hours, add this difference into additional column. The main thing is that some cells of dateto are empty. In this case I should take "dateto" as current date and time.

The second thing is to add column with if statment. If the difference between datefrom and dateto more than 3 hours than 1, else 0.

Now I can calculate only differences in hours. The main problem is with empty cells and additional column with statement when hours more than 3

```
select id, DateFrom, DateTo, UserId,
(Datefrom-DateTO) as hours
 from table

order by id
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxpAU.jpg)

Comment: is it `mysql` or `sql-server`? Pick one!

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: What have you tried so far. A SQL question without any SQL is a bad question. You want to use daddiff and a maybe a case or isnull statement

Comment: Generally you should post what you tried - not ask others to do it for you.

Comment: Can I use case statement? The main idea is that i should mark the Id when the differences in hours is more than three

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example for MS SQL:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate ='2007-06-05'
SET @EndDate ='2007-08-05'

SELECT DATEDIFF(Hour, @StartDate, @EndDate) AS NewDate
--Return Value = 1464 Hour


SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, @StartDate, @EndDate) AS NewDate
--Return Value = 87840 minute


SELECT DATEDIFF(second, @StartDate, @EndDate) AS NewDate
--Return Value = 5270400 second
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need some Control [Flow Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html).
With the select, you will need:

```
SELECT id, datefrom, dateto, userid
```

You can use IFNULL(), if dateto is NULL, then it will return [CURDATE()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_curdate.asp):

```
IFNULL(dateto, CURDATE())
```

And one `IF(condition, truth, false)`, but first, you will need the diference in hours. You can calculate with some [Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html), you will get the diference between the dates, convert it to seconds, and divide by 3600):

```
TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(IFNULL(dateto, CURDATE()), datefrom)) / 3600
```

Now, check if it's bigger than 3:

```
IF(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(IFNULL(dateto, CURDATE()), datefrom)) / 3600 > 3, 1, 0)
```

At the end, it will be like:

```
SELECT
  id,
  datefrom,
  dateto,
  userid,
  TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(IFNULL(dateto, CURDATE()), datefrom)) / 3600
  IF(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(IFNULL(dateto, CURDATE()), datefrom)) / 3600 > 3, 1, 0),
FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks all.

I wrote code in Periscope. I dont know why but I can use there some functions as TIME_TO_SEC, TIMEDIFF, TIMESTAMPDIFF.

The final code is below.

```
SELECT id
, DateFrom
, DateTo
, UserId
, CASE 
 WHEN DateFrom is null OR (DateFrom - DateTo) < '0 days 00:00:00'
 THEN (NOW() - DateTo)
 ELSE (DateFrom - DateTo)   
 END as hours 
, CASE 
 WHEN (DateFrom IS NULL AND (NOW() - DateTo) > '0 days 03:00:00') OR (DateFrom is not null and ((DateFrom - DateTo) > '0 days 03:00:00') OR (DateFrom - DateTo) < '0 days 00:00:00')
 THEN 1
 ELSE 0 
 END as Attribute
```